# How to get two columns Values based on Where function in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, csv

The Question is:
Based on the `user_id` column, I want to get the values of `rating` and `product_id` columns. There can be multiple entries with the same user_id. I want to get all users records with the `rating` and `product_id` columns value But for the movies where the user didn't rate the movie should be displayed as Nan but still, the `product_id` should be retrieved. Following is the table with some data provided.

```
| product_id  | user_id         | user_name                                    | rating |
|-------------|-----------------|----------------------------------------------|--------|
|  B0009XRZ92 | A2JFZLAUG3YFQ7  |  Entropy Babe "EB"                           | 5      |
|  B0009XRZ92 | A22HGAAO8KZ2N3  |  R.   Metzelar                               | 5      |
|  B000067A8B |  A2NJO6YE954DBH |  Lawrance M. Bernabo                         | 4      |
|  B0009XRZ92 |  A3HE4MYMWK4AER |  Rebecca M. Eddy "Foster Mom and   Untbunny" | 5      |
|  B003A3R3ZY | A9A2PR663ED1V   |  Roger D. Goff                               | 5      |
|  B0009XRZ92 | A2MRZDJF90JC1U  |  Suzanne K. Armstrong "Suzy Q"               | 5      |
|  B0009XRZ92 |  A2YNBDT3170PCR |  C.   O'Hern                                 | 5      |
|  B0009XRZ92 |  A10VJ7BDVCPKEZ |  Carol S. Bottom                             | 5      |
|  B0009XRZ92 |  AAAQO894MG80B  |  Paul J. Michko                              | 5      |
|  B00067BBQE | A9A2PR663ED1V   |  Roger D. Goff                               | 5      |
|  B0009XRZ92 | A31S5QUMFR8NH2  |  Dana L. Jordan "Mom of Twins"               | 5      |
|  B0009XRZ92 |  A2DS24DHXUH0GM |  Gaz    Rev(iewer)                           | 4      |
|  B00006AUMZ |  A2NJO6YE954DBH |  Lawrance M. Bernabo                         | 4      |
|  B0009XRZ92 |  A16FRHL2ZC7EUR |  M.   Claytor                                | 5      |
|  B0009XRZ92 | A3AV8R0A62PP1N  |  MARCUSHELBLINZ "mmmacman"                   | 5      |
|  B0009XRZ92 |  A3QN84C38DE9FU |  Gillian M. Kratzer                          | 5      |
|  B0009XRZ92 |  A36MLTLVQFEQYL |  Yossarian "alienated socialist"             | 5      |
|  B00006AUMD |  A2NJO6YE954DBH |  Lawrance M. Bernabo                         | 4      |
```

> What I want to do is:
>
> To take one `user_id` at a time  and display the `rating` and `product_id`
>   columns value for that user for all the movies in the table and if the
>   user didn't rate some movies then the record should be displayed with
>   the `product_id` value and `rating` as Nan and the whole process should be repeated for all the users.

For Example, the record for `user_id: A2NJO6YE954DBH` will look like this:

```
| product_id | rating |
|------------|--------|
| B000067A8B | 4      |
| B00006AUMD | 4      |
| B00006AUMD | 4      |
| B0009XRZ92 | Nan    |
| B003A3R3ZY | Nan    |
| B00067BBQE | Nan    |
|     .      |   .    |
|     .      |   .    |
|     .      |    .   |
```

I've tried to write the code for this using Pandas Library but couldn't help myself. This is All i did but its not outputing what I want.

```
import pandas as pd
df =pd.read_csv('out.csv')
unique_users=df.user_id.unique()
for x, y in enumerate(unique_users):
    print(df[['rating','product_id']].where(df.user_id==y))
```

Please help me out.. Thanks

Comment: Do we have `y` defined in the `user_id` column ? id ont see that in sample

Comment: We are getting the value of y in for loop

Comment: user `A2JFZLAUG3YFQ24` is not in the example df, can you add some samples?

Comment: @anky_91 I have edited the question. there were some errors in the table. Hopefully, you'll get now.

Comment: @FaizanKhan i think best use pivot table here, check answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If i understand you correctly, you can use [`pd.pivot_table()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.pivot_table.html) here:

```
df_new=df.pivot_table(index='user_id',columns='product_id',values='rating').rename_axis(None,1)
print(df_new)


                     B000067A8B     B00006AUMD     B00006AUMZ     B00067BBQE   \
user_id                                                                         
  A10VJ7BDVCPKEZ             NaN            NaN            NaN            NaN   
  A16FRHL2ZC7EUR             NaN            NaN            NaN            NaN   
  A2DS24DHXUH0GM             NaN            NaN            NaN            NaN   
  A2NJO6YE954DBH             4.0            4.0            4.0            NaN   
  A2YNBDT3170PCR             NaN            NaN            NaN            NaN   
  A36MLTLVQFEQYL             NaN            NaN            NaN            NaN   
  A3HE4MYMWK4AER             NaN            NaN            NaN            NaN   
  A3QN84C38DE9FU             NaN            NaN            NaN            NaN   
  AAAQO894MG80B              NaN            NaN            NaN            NaN   
 A22HGAAO8KZ2N3              NaN            NaN            NaN            NaN   
 A2JFZLAUG3YFQ7              NaN            NaN            NaN            NaN   
 A2MRZDJF90JC1U              NaN            NaN            NaN            NaN   
 A31S5QUMFR8NH2              NaN            NaN            NaN            NaN   
 A3AV8R0A62PP1N              NaN            NaN            NaN            NaN   
 A9A2PR663ED1V               NaN            NaN            NaN            5.0   

                     B0009XRZ92     B003A3R3ZY   
user_id                                          
  A10VJ7BDVCPKEZ             5.0            NaN  
  A16FRHL2ZC7EUR             5.0            NaN  
  A2DS24DHXUH0GM             4.0            NaN  
  A2NJO6YE954DBH             NaN            NaN  
  A2YNBDT3170PCR             5.0            NaN  
  A36MLTLVQFEQYL             5.0            NaN  
  A3HE4MYMWK4AER             5.0            NaN  
  A3QN84C38DE9FU             5.0            NaN  
  AAAQO894MG80B              5.0            NaN  
 A22HGAAO8KZ2N3              5.0            NaN  
 A2JFZLAUG3YFQ7              5.0            NaN  
 A2MRZDJF90JC1U              5.0            NaN  
 A31S5QUMFR8NH2              5.0            NaN  
 A3AV8R0A62PP1N              5.0            NaN  
 A9A2PR663ED1V               NaN            5.0
```

Comment: Thanks for responding. I have shown the picture of the output table for one user which I want to get. and the same is require for each user

Comment: so are you keeping every user in seperate dataframes or all in one? if all in one, can you post the expected output with 2 users?

Comment: @FaizanKhan Done. :) upvoted.  if you think my answer has helped you solve the problem, please consider accepting the answer by clicking on the tick mark(grey coloured) on the left of the answer. You earn +2 as well. :)

Comment: Yes, definitely I'll do. I'm just writing data into CSV file through your code and then I'll mark it correct.  Thanks That was really helpful

Comment: @FaizanKhan Sure, Thanks

Comment: Can you please how we can write pivot_table to csv file?

Comment: `df_new.to_csv(filepath+filename,index=False)`

Comment: When writing to the same file (which was input file) for the first time, it works but if you want to write to new CSV file which doesn't have any data or doing it for 2nd or more time, it gives an error. the error is about the values='rating' attribute in the pivot_table function.

Comment: may be you have to rerun the entire code before saving it to another file

Answer (score 1):

try

```
 print(df[df.user_id==y][['rating','product_id']])
```

Comment: Thanks for responding. Is there something we can do which show all other movies too which users did not rate as I have displayed in the output table for a particular user in the question. The rating should be nan but product id should be correct for those movies

Comment: I've shown the table for just one user in the question and this should be done for each user.

Comment: I got the right answer. though if you find my question logically valid, please upvote. so I can upvote those who helped me. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can extract rows where `user_id` equals to a specific value by doing:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv('out.csv')
unique_users = df.user_id.unique()
for x, y in enumerate(unique_users):
    print(df.loc[df['user_id'] == y])
```

Comment: Thanks for responding but I want to display only two columns and some movies which user did not rate should also display with rating as Nan. Can you help in this regard

Comment: You can refer to the output table for a particular user which I have shown in the question.

Comment: If u find my question logically valid, Please upvote. Thanks